# I need to put hyperlinks with php in every row of a table. if a row is pressed it will be redirected to another page

Tags: php, hyperlink, plpgsql

I'm doing a php table which has different stores.
I need that when each store is pressed it goes to a page to show their products.
A summary of my code is:

```
   <?php

      require("../config/conexion.php");
      include("../template/header.html");

      $query = "SELECT DISTINCT name FROM stores ORDER BY name;";
      $result = $db_g111 -> prepare($query);
      $result -> execute();
      $stores = $result -> fetchAll();

   ?>


<body>  
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($stores as $store) {
                echo "<tr> <td>$store[0]</td> </tr>";
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

i have try many ways but never with success. I would like to send the hyperlink to "store_information.php".

Comment: how store-information.php fetches which store details to show ? what is database table structure of stores ?

Comment: Did you try to output a link (an `<a>`-tag) inside the `<td>...</td>`? Where exactly are you stuck? _"i have try many ways"_ - Please post your attempt and explain what should happen and what does happen.

Comment: i tried to put links inside of: echo "<tr> <td>$store[0]</td> </tr>"; and I can't . I'm sure is easy but is the first time I work with this, I tried puting this:
        echo "<tr> <td><a href="pages/store_info.php">store[0]</a></td> </tr>";

Comment: I also need to send the name of the store to the other page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, you should try as follows...

echo statement in your comment is missing some single quotes.

```
echo '<tr><td><a href="paginas/tienda_info.php">' .tienda[0]. '</a></td></tr>';
```

Ideally your echo should be

```
echo "<tr><td>" .$store[0]. "</td></tr>";
```

If you want to assign link to whole tr tag, then you can try it with jquery.

```
 echo '<tr class="linktowholerow"><td>' .tienda[0]. '</td></tr>';
```

And jquery as :

```
$(function() {
  $(".linktowholerow").on("click", function() {
      location.href="paginas/tienda_info.php";
  });
});
```